# changing attribute of a span element using javascript where the class changes dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, dom

heres the problem, our css classnames for a span element keeps changing whenever we generate. so to simplify, we have a span element

```
<tr>
   <td>
       <span class=1234>My Name is BouncingHippo</span>
   </td>
        ....other well-defined DOM elements with id etc...
 </tr>
```

i have a radio button somewhere on the html, where onchange, it will change the font-color of the span element.

The span element has no id, no name, and a span class that changes all the time. My current method is brute-force `getElementsByTagName()` to return a specific line using `innerHTML` for every `<tr>` and insert the style attribute that way.

Is there a better way for this? Reason why span class changes every generation is for security purposes stipulated by our client..

**EDIT 1**

a rough concept on jsfiddle of the brute-force method that i have yet to get it working..
http://jsfiddle.net/3jVnJ/1/

Comment: Could you include your current code?

Comment: Maybe target it from further up the DOM e.g. table tr td span - would work better if the table or it's parent has an ID or CLASS you could hang on to.

Comment: Could you show a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) to show us what's going on? (Just to demonstrate, it doesn't have to be accurate beyond reflecting the changing class-names and insertion of new HTML).

Comment: and I'm assuming jQuery isn't an option?

Comment: You haven't described a meaningful algorithm for finding this `<span>`.  Is it the only `<span>` tag in this particular table?  Is it the only `<span>` tag with a class of all digits?  Before one could code how to do this, you have to figure out what algorithm would be used for finding it?  Can you at least require an id on the desired table?  Or locate the identify the table by its location relative to other things?

Comment: @BillyMoat thank you Billy Moat, i have decided to try your method of locating the parent table by `location using getELmentsByTagNames()` and working my way down to the location of the span element using `innerHTML`

Comment: It's generally not good to look for things with innerHTML and different browsers will return you differently formatted innerHTML, some of which is different than what was originally in the page (particular IE).  It's much better to use DOM element navigation and searching.  See my answer below for one method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one option based on the idea in your jsFiddle:

```
function findParentTag(obj, tag) {
    tag = tag.toUpperCase();
    while (obj && obj.tagName !== tag) {
        obj = obj.parentNode;
    }
    return(obj);
}

function changeColor(obj){
    var table = findParentTag(obj, "table");
    var spans = table.getElementsByTagName("span");
    for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
        if (spans[i].className) {
            spans[i].style.color = "red";
            break;
        }
    }
}                
    ​
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/kZQJq/

Answer (score 1):

You could print out, from the server at generation, a js script tag with a variable that is the currently generated class name. Then you use the variable where you need to know what class that span is.

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is:
Element  selection with attribute A
dom=for each (e in document.gEBTN('E')) if (e.A) e

so for you it would be like smth `for each (e in document.gEBTN('span')) if (e.class=="1234") e.className=”changedFont”;`